# Rsync ask for password even though I can SSH in without a password using a key

Tags: ssh, rsync, openssh

This is the command I'm using:

```
sudo rsync -rvz -e 'ssh -p 1111' ******@111.111.111.111:/home/sql/ /media/disk1/bd92a143-c4d7-4b70-bb6a-6576678fa96b/user/Backups/sql/4-6-2015
```

Any advice?

Comment: When you can ssh without a password, is that within a sudo as well?  Is it sudo that's prompting you for the password or rsync?

Comment: Both are prompting me for a password, but it's the remote machine I'm worried about.

Comment: Can you do `sudo ssh -p 1111 ***@111.111.111.111` without the ssh prompting you?

Comment: I should have tried that. It looks like it only ask for a password, on the remote, when I use sudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using `sudo` which is using different RSA keys (`root` private keys), instead of your user private keys.

So either don't use `sudo`, or add RSA keys of `root` account on the remote.

To verify this, add `-vvv` parameter to `ssh` command to see the verbose output.

You may also use `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` to add your user keys, so you can be properly identified.